# In Stata, how do I manipulate matrix elements by their name?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, stata

In Stata, after a regression I know it is possible to call the elements of stored results by name.  For example, if I want to manipulate the coefficient on the variable `precip`, I just type `_b[precip]`.  My question is how do I do the same after the `tabstat` command?  For example, say I want to multiply the coefficient on `precip` by the sample mean of `precip`:

```
    reg --variables in regression--
    tabstat --variables in regression--
    mat X=r(StatTotal)
    mat Y=_b[precip]*X[1,precip]
```

Ah, if only it were that simple.  But alas, in the last line X[1, precip] is invalid syntax.  Oddly, Stata does recognize `display X[1, precip]`.  And Stata would know what I'm trying to do if instead of `precip` I used the column number where `precip` appears in the `X` vector.  If I were just doing this operation once, no problem.  But I need to do this operation several times (for several different model specifications) and for several variables which change position in the vector from one model to the next, so I cannot just use the column number.

Comment: Please post your problem with complete variable names starting from `sysuse auto` followed by something like `regress price mpg foreign weight`, so that everybody is on the common wavelength. `tabstat` is a very superficial command, although that might be a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not yet sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but here's my attempt to reproduce what you are doing:

```
    sysuse auto, clear
    regress price mpg foreign weight
    tabstat mpg foreign weight, save
    matrix X = r(StatTotal)
    matrix Y = _b[mpg]*X[1, colnumb(X, "mpg") ]
```

If you need to put this into a cycle, that's doable, too:

```
    matrix bb = e(b)
    local explvar : colnames bb
    foreach x in `explvar' {
      if "`x'" != "_cons" {
        matrix Y_`x' = _b[`x'] * X[1, colnumb(X, "`x'")]
      }
      else {
        matrix Y_`x' = _b[`x']
      }
    }
```

You'd probably want to put this into a `program` that you will call after each regression model estimation call, e.g.:

```
    program define reg2mat , prefix( name )

      if "`e(cmd)'" != "regress" {
        // this will intentionally produce an error
        regress
      }

      tempname bb

      matrix `bb' = e(b)
      local explvar : colnames `bb'
      foreach x in `explvar' {
        if "`x'" != "_cons" {
          matrix `prefix'_`x' = _b[`x'] * X[1, colnumb(X, "`x'")]
        }
        else {
          matrix `prefix'_`x' = _b[`x']
        }
      }
    end // of reg2mat
```

At many levels, it is not ideal, as it manipulates with the (global) matrices in Stata memory; most of the time, it is a bad idea, as the programs should only manipulate with objects local to them.

I suspect that what you want to do is addressed, in one way or another, by either omnipowerful `margins` command, or by an appropriate `predict`, or by `matrix score` (which is the low level version of `predict`). Attributing the effects to a variable only makes sense when your regressors are orthogonal, which only happens in carefully designed and conducted experiments.